# I want my clock program to display the output as 00:00 instead it displays it as 0:0 even though I have used stream manipulators

Tags: c++

So I made a sloppy clock program as an assignment. It works fine however I want the output to display each cout as **"01:02"**, instead it displays **"1:2"**, even though I think I have written all the right manipulators. This is my whole program.

```
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout << fixed << right;
    cout.fill(0);
    for (int m = 0; m < 59; m++)
    {
        for (int s = 0; s < 59; s++)
        {
            this_thread::sleep_for(
                chrono::seconds(1));
            system("cls");
            cout << setw(2) << m << ":";
            cout << setw(2) << s << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the null character to fill (which is not visible).

```cpp
cout.fill(0);
```

What you probably meant was to use the ASCII character `0`, like this:

```cpp
cout.fill('0');
```

Comment: `'0'` is not necessarily an ASCII character.

Comment: You are correct.  I can't believe I missed that. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You also need to do a [`setfill('0')`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) in addition with `setw()`.

`setw()` simply sets the minimum width for the formatted output operation. The unused part of the field's width defaults to spaces. `setfill()` changes that.